# Need regex to extrude class values

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I have this kind of code

```
<div class="test"><a href="../toto"><i class="test toto">toto</i></a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="../titi"><i class="test titi">titi</i></a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="../tutu"><i class="test tutu">tutu</i></a></div>
```

Note that the content of the classes is unknown but i want to have at the end an array which contain in this case :

```
["test toto", "test titi", "test tutu"]
```

Comment: So you specifically want the `<i>` element classes, and *not* the `<div>` classes, right?

Comment: PHP or Javascript? You mentioned both in tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var j = $.map($("[class]"), function(val, key) {
  return $(val).find("[class]").attr("class")
});
```

```js
var j = $.map($("[class]"), function(val, key) {
  return $(val).find("[class]").attr("class")
});
$("body").append(JSON.stringify(j, null, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"><a href="../toto"><i class="test toto">toto</i></a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="../titi"><i class="test titi">titi</i></a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="../tutu"><i class="test tutu">tutu</i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way with PHP is to use XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($yourhtml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$textNodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]/a/i/@class');

foreach ($textNodeList as $textNode) {
    echo "\n" . $textNode->nodeValue;
}
```

Note: as  Niet the Dark Absol notices it, if the div tag has several classes, you can replace the equality with `contains()`, so:

```
$textNodeList = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"test")]/a/i/@class');
```

Comment: I would suggest `[contains(@class,'test')]` to improve support for more than a single class on the containers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I will add a note about.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get)

```
var arr = $('.test > a > i').map(function(){
    return this.className;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Incorrect. Selector does not match the `<i>` elements because they are `.test > a > i`, not `.test > i` ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
<i.+?class="(.+)"
```

javaScript Code:

```
var re = /<i.+?class="(.+)"/g;
var str = '<div class="test"><a href="../toto"><i class="test toto">toto</i></a></div>\n<div class="test"><a href="../titi"><i class="test titi">titi</i></a></div>\n<div class="test"><a href="../tutu"><i class="test tutu">tutu</i></a></div>';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery map()**

```
var arr = [];
$('.test a i').map(function(){
    arr.push(this.className);
});
console.log(arr);
```

**Using PHP regex**

```
$pattern = '/<i class="test(.*)(">)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $m);
$arr = array_map(function($v){
    return "test " . $v;
}, $m[1]);

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mE9rD7/1)

Comment: You copied @Amit Joki answer.

Comment: @Scott Erm, no? Amit's answer uses `.map` properly, this one doesn't :p So if it *is* a copy, it's a bad one.